# Django: "show databases" functionality?

Tags: django, mysql-python

I have a weird legacy database use-case: I have multiple databases, with (1) exactly the same schema, but (2) very different datasets.  Databases, *entire* databases, with this schema, are being added to the total dataset every week.

Is there a way to (1) introspect *the server* to find out what databases are available, and if so, is there a way to (2) route to the correct database by URL, rather than by the current per-model solution (since my models don't change, only the associated underlying tables)?

Can this introspection be made dynamic, so every time someone hits the home page I can show them the list of available databases?

A generic solution is preferable, of course, but a MySQL-only solution is currently acceptable.

(The use case in the European Molecular Biology Lab's genome library, which is published every few months as a suite of MySQL database dumps, one database per species, with a core schema of about twenty tables which map nicely to six or so apps.  The schema is stable and hasn't changed in years.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are able to [run any raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/), and `show databases` is not exception. But it will be hard to change list of available databases and to switch between them. I'm afraid this will require modification or monkey patching of django's internals.

Update: Wait! I've looked into the code behind the `django.db.connections` and found that if you just extend `settings.DATABASES` in runtime, then you'll be able to use `SomeModel.objects.using('some-new-database').all()` in the code. Have not tested, but belive this should work!

Comment: Thanks.  I looked into your suggestion and it works fine.  That and some threadlocal stuff, and I can use some middleware to switch databases as needed.  Sadly, Django *can't* use the EMBL datasets, as they're explicitly made with PK-free tables.  Such a hack...

Comment: Frozen genome datasets provided by the European Molecular Biology Library.  See ensembl.org for details.  We're trying to use these datasets as an adjunct to a commercial project, and the question is what layer do we start at: the database, the customized ORM (written in very verbose, very pedantic Perl), or higher?

Comment: It turns out that I had to use SqlAlchemy to access the EMBL sets, so the website's a weird hybrid of Django's ORM for some things, and SqlAlchemy for others.